# Using boost::asio to perform unicast messaging

Tags: c++, windows

What is the simplest way in C++ (an actual code example would be great) to establish/open a UDP [unicast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicast) connection if I know the IP address and port?

The resolver/query/endpoint/iterator stuff seems a bit like overkill and at my level of understanding, so far a bit confusing.

First of all I'm new to Boost, but I have done some work with the [Boost.Asio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asio_C++_library) library.

Comment: The [ASIO tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial.html) should give you a good start if you're generally familiar with Boost and C++. The key is to make the `io_service` run(), possibly in a separate thread or otherwise as the main program loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example here that uses resolvers etc.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime4.html

If you wish to use an ip address that you already have, you can do something like this:

```
boost::asio::ip::address ip_add = boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("192.168.1.1");
tcp::endpoint remoteEndpoint( ip_add , portno );
```

This is for TCP, but I expect you can do something similar for UDP.

Comment: Thanks, I see what I can do with this.